# How to find the inverse Laplace transform of this function?

Tags: laplace-transform

$F(s) = \dfrac{s}{s+3}$
I can't find this term in any Laplace lists around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $F(s) = \dfrac{s}{s+3} = \dfrac{(s+3)-3}{s+3} = 1-\dfrac{3}{s+3}$.

Can you find $1$ and $\dfrac{1}{s+3}$ in your Laplace table?

Comment: What's F(s) = 1 converted to the original funtion? Dictra Deltafunction doesn't ring a bell

Comment: The inverse Laplace transform of $1$ is the Dirac Delta function $\delta(t)$. What's the problem with that?